# Is it possible to change Firebase Analytics User Properties from a backend?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

**Overview:** I would like to send targeted push notifications in my Native Mobile App by using the segmentation offered by Firebase. The way I would like to configure this segmentation is by leveraging on custom Firebase Analytics User Properties, like specific preferences or other business specific parameters.

I've seen that is possible to update User Properties by means of the Firebase SDK and through them I will update a "custom ID" user property which helps me identifying my users; on the other side I would like to update other user parameters, which should help me segmenting users, through a backend process.

**The Problem:** is that I've not found how to update User Properties from a backend side, like through APIs or something like that.

Have someone figured out to implement this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no server-side or REST API for Google Analytics for Firebase at the moment.

The two options that I know of:

- Send the properties from your server to the client, and use the Firebase SDK on the client to get those properties in to Analytics.
- Hook your Firebase analytics up to BigQuery, store the additional information from your server into BigQuery too, and then join then in your own analysis.

Comment: Thanks Frank, this is very helpful. Just for having a clearer understanding on the second option, when you say that I can then join BigQuery updated information into my analysis do you mean that will be updated User Properties by storing new info into BigQuery?

Comment: If you store the additional properties in BigQuery from your server, and have Firebase stream the analytics event to BigQuery, you can join those two in your own queries to get the combined results.

Comment: But once combined these two information into BigQuery are these available, in particular the ones stored by my server, in Firebase in order to send targeted push notification based on these new information?

Comment: You'd have to call into BigQuery from your server-side that then calls FCM based on the query results.

Comment: So in that case I will be able to target my users backend-side, but not leveraging on Firebase segmentation capability based on User Properties, correct?

Comment: Any updates in this topic?